# Python: load a UI from a separate file

Tags: python, tkinter

G'day All,

I'm using tkinter for my GUI.  Currently when I write an app most of the code is the interface widgets.  I know how to import a file of defined functions and use them and I want to be able to "import" the UI.  That way I can reuse the UI file and declutter the main app.

The conceptual hurdle I'm facing is that if I declare a window:

```
main = Tk()
```

how do I then populate "main" from another module?

Thanks,
A.

Comment: Try something like `import my_gui_lib; my_gui_lib.main.doStuff()` except with linebreak instead of semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to not do `main=Tk()`. Instead, have your UI inherit from Tk. For example:

```
# in ui.py
import Tkinter as tk
class MyApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

# in main.py
import ui
def main():
    main = ui.MyApp()
    main.mainloop()
```

If you don't like inheriting from `tk.Tk`, your other option is to create your main window and then pass it as an argument to whatever code you have that creates the GUI. For example:

```
# ui.py
def CreateUI(root)
    ...

# main.py
import ui
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    ui.CreateUI(root)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could pass it as a parameter like `import my_gui; my_gui.create(main)`; but for most situations I would recommend working the other way round -- have the GUI file be the file that you execute, and it imports the number-crunching functions from your core-functionality library